# The .forEach function logs all element instead of only the element clicked

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let posts = document.querySelectorAll('.update-btn');
  posts.forEach(post => post.addEventListener('click', loadEdit(post)))
  document.querySelector('#post_submit').addEventListener('click', newPost);
})
```

I feel like it has something to do with it being in DOM. "posts" are an array of buttons with the class ".update-btn", so I used forEach with addEventListener so that a button clicked can be identified in the function I made (loadEdit(post)):

```
function loadEdit(post) {
    console.log("Clicked post: ", post)
```

However, it seems that the console logs all elements (of .update-btn) automatically within reload of the page – without any button being clicked, when I just want the element that would be clicked.

Comment: You are executing `loadEdit(post)` in the loop. I think you want to pass a reference to it (`post.addEventlistener("click",loadEdit)`) which will pass the event to loadEdit and you can use the event.target or event.currentTarget in loadEdit to determine the actual element that was clicked.

Comment: I think you are looking for this `posts.forEach(post => post.addEventListener('click', function(){loadEdit(post)}))`

Comment: Thank you, `posts.forEach(post => post.addEventListener('click', function(){loadEdit(post)}))` worked!